# NFC Tags with Wireless Network Configuration not working with Android Pie

Tags: android, wifi, nfc, android-9.0-pie

**Preface:**
I have spent a good deal of time trying to find an answer online but most articles link to 4-6 year old info on the topic which is no longer relevant for current day implementations. Specifically they refer to versions of android pre-pie OS (Pie does not seem to support the same features).

**Problem:**
I have an NFC tag with my home WiFi network configuration on it so that guests can have their android devices automatically connect to the network without needing to plug in the code. My android device (NEXUS 5X) running Oreo or later prompt the user to connect to the WiFi as intended. All tests with my android device (Pixel 2) running Pie instead give bring up a new tag collected window (no option to connect to network). Other NFC tag controls like websites, destination address, volume control, etc. work just fine.

**Questions:**
1) What changed with Android Pie that is preventing WiFi configuration to not work?
2) Is there a workaround that can be used to allow Android Pie devices to connect to the WiFi network using an nfc tag?